# how to run tomcat in https and port 80?

Tags: java, apache, tomcat, centos, iptables

I am trying to host a website on Centos + tomcat7 , if I run tomcat7 on port 80 everything works fine i.e. 74.208.164.45 but if I want to access it using https://74.208.164.45/ ,it doesn't work , but If I try like this https://74.208.164.45:8443/ after adding the keystore , then it works fine.

So, I need a way to run tomcat on 80 and https , i.e. https://74.208.164.45/ should work fine on port 80.
Now,I am trying only with Tomcat but if it's totally not possible then I can use some Apache http server to redirect to tomcat using AJP connectors but that is the last thing I would prefer to do .
Also, can we do something with the IPTables?

Comment: I'm not an expert on HTTP however port 80 is the default for HTTP traffic, HTTPS is 443. I'd imagine your router should be able to redirect 443 to the appropriate machine. Perhaps a firewall is blocking. Do you know that 443 is open?

Comment: Change server.xml in tomcat conf directory to use 445 in place of 8443.

Comment: 8443 is open , 443 is not open

Comment: what will happen if I change to 445 , uday?

Comment: Yes it is possible to run tomcat with HTTPS on port 443.  You just need to configure it correctly and run it as 'root' to allow it to bind on that port.  (But you are presumably already running as 'root' to get Tomcat to bind on port 80!)

Comment: *"8443 is open , 443 is not open"* ... So open it!  Check the firewall settings.

Comment: shall I change 8443 to 443 in server.xml?

Comment: Why is 443 not open? Is it in use already or shutdown by a firewall or something.

Comment: This is the xml conf, <Connector port="8443" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol"
               maxThreads="150" SSLEnabled="true" scheme="https" secure="true"
               clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS" keystoreFile="xxxxxx"
               keystorePass="xxxxx"/>

Comment: thanks for all your help, I really appreciate everybody's help

Comment: How if you try this sample URL?
https://74.208.164.45:80

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to change the Connector port for https from the default value of "8443" to "443" in server.xml

The default looks something like this:

```
<Connector port="8443" protocol="HTTP/1.1" SSLEnabled="true"
           maxThreads="150" scheme="https" secure="true"
           clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS" />
```

See [SSL/TLS Configuration HOW-TO](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/ssl-howto.html) from the Tomcat docs on how to setup SSL

Answer (score 1):

This could be the full format in the server.xml

```
<Connector port="80" protocol="HTTP/1.1" connectionTimeout="20000" redirectPort="443" />

<Connector port="443" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol" maxThreads="150" SSLEnabled="true" scheme="https" secure="true" clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS"  keystoreFile="/.keystore" keystorePass="Pa$$W0rd" />
```